# backbone local storage adding twice

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

How do you work around backbone local storage adding twice.

I am getting double values for everything in mu local storage.  The local storage also adds a key number and the key id sequences are out of order:

```
     drink: function() {
        var val = $('#new_booze').val();
        console.log(val);
        if (val === this.lastTitle) {
            return;
        }
        this.lastTitle = val;

        this.collection.create({
            boozeTitle: val,
            id: this.makeID(val)
        });
        this.collection.fetch({
            reset: true
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in backbone local-storage's create function

```
create: function(model) {
  if (!model.id) model.set(model.idAttribute, guid());
  this.data[model.id] = model;
  this.save();
  return model;
},
```

setting the id & saving, both trigger a save on the model.

you can avoid this by using a fast non-cryptographic hash as the id since backbone will do a no-op if you add two models with the same id.

```
makeID: function(string) {
  var hash = 0;
  if(string.length === 0) {
     return hash;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
  {
    char = string.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
    hash = hash & hash;
  }
 return hash;
};
```

This has a few disadvantages, since its a hashing function, each title can only be added once, and theres a greater chance of a hash collision.